# When is the relyingpartytrustid set by ADFS?

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs

I had a couple of "Acceptance transform rules" defined for AD which suddenly stopped working.. It looks like the relyingpartytrustid-claim (http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid) don't exist in the "acceptance transform rules"-step in the ADFS (2012 R2) pipeline anymore. The strange thing is that it was there before, but now I can't see it until the next step in the ADFS claimstransformation pipeline (issuance transform rules for relying parties).

**Does anyone know exactly when the relyingpartytrustid-claim is issued by ADFS?** I can't find any information on how/when these claims are issued.

Claim-rule that worked before and then suddenly stopped working:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid"]
 => add(store = "CustomAttributeStore", types = ("http://domain.no/context/FmApplicationId", "http://domain.no/context/AdfsApplicationId", "http://domain.no/context/CustomProperty"), query = "GetApplicationAttributes#FmApplicationId,AdfsApplicationId,CustomProperty", param = c.Value);
```

The following rule results in "temp" beeing issued if the rule is placed under "acceptance transform rules", but not when it is placed under "issuance transform rules"

```
NOT EXISTS([Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid"])
=> issue(Type = "http://domain.no/temp", Value = "dontexist");
```

Answer (score 0):

The claim http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid is part of the Request Context provided by Web Application Proxy to AD FS during authentication of external users.